# Hibernate bean validation issue

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am using spring 3.1 with hibernate validator 4.2. I observe that hibernate validation gets invoked two times:
One at controller level when i use method like:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmit(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {....}
```

And 2nd time when entities are persisted as part of:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(..)
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(..)
org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(..)
```

I believe it makes more sense to valid at controller level and display error page with error messages. And anyway, doing same validation two times in flow not good.
I found in hibernate doc that it can be turned off by setting `hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners` to false in hibernate configuration but it is not recommended.

So what is recommended approach for validation? Also in my particular case 2nd validation causes trouble because I have a field '`confirmPassword`' which is required for validation when user submits form but is not required in table so whenever i have to save, update user, I have to set `confirmPassword` field unnecessarily just to make validation pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation isn't an easy thing in spite of appearances.

The *frontend validation* is for the user that fills the form,and could change from a view to another view (different messages for example). The message for a required field in the view should be "The field is mandatory !", in the backend when the entity is persisted : "field cannot be null".

The *backend validation* should occur ALWAYS when a class is saved, consider infact that  a persistent entity could be saved without passing from the view (for example from a batch that receive data from a webservice or from queues ora another source..).

If you put a validation annotation  at entity level you enforce a contract on that class that is independent from the fact that the class has been used in a view or not.

ConfirmPassword is a view field, so i think should not be present as field in the entity (for example, I developed a similar case  with JSF, i  put confirmPassword in the ManagedBean related to that view and not in the entity, the entity  contain only the password field).

Summarizing therefore i think is correct doing the 'same' validation twice.

Comment: So you suggest I should have two pojo beans one userForm for view validation and other user for saving to database. And I shd have validation annotation on both. Its very common to see examples where one single bean is used both for jsp form and saving to database, therby saving code for copying fields from one bean to another. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: ..in my experience is not (always) possibile to have one single class for the view and for the database, consider that not rarely in the view are present fields that come from many persistent entities (i call it a 'view' on the domain model) and moreover (as in your case with confirmPassword) there are fields that has no sense to persist.In my case a have a bean(userForm) that hold the persistent class bean (sometimes refers more persistent beans) : in my case confirmPassword/confirmEmail are in the 'form bean' and the fields password/email are in the "entity" (persistent beans).

Comment: hmm, yes things you said makes perfect sense for using two classes of objects VOs and DTOs. I feel the code will have many statements like: 'user.setEmail(userForm.getEmail())' which doesn't seem good. As far as i remember even spring roo generates code using same class for view and db.

Comment: uhm...i try to clarify better,I don't like much DTO (many books consider it an antipattern...for example EJB 3 In Action). DTO has a COST that is often unjustified. Notice that i don't rely on ugly "copy code" in my example because i keep confirmPassword in separate class (managedbean : the 'viewBean'), and 'password' field is declared only in persistent class, and make JSF page point directly to password field (example : managedBean.persistentBean.password) . So the user directly fill the password field from the JSF page (no copy code needed)

Comment: I am not aware of jsf, ejb much so let me know if I have understood you correctly. So are you suggesting to have single form backed by multiple beans on server side - a form bean for all view only fields and entity beans for persistant fields? If it is so I am not sure how it will work out in spring-mvc. As far as i know it supports single form bean per jsp form specified in jsp as - '<form:form commandName="userForm" method="post">'.

Comment: .. in my case jsf not jsp.. (JSF now support JSR-303 validation api). I have some cases with a managedBean (you userForm) that refers one or more persistent beans. In this way I avoid to copy everytime the properties...Anyway i just try to give you some ideas because i had same your dubts...now (partially) solved. I think that the silver bullet for validation does not exists.

Comment: hmm.. I am not sure how to make userform refer persistant beans in spring. Do you mean that you composed userForm with required persistant beans?

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the use case and to a certain degree on personal taste. @obe6 suggest two separate beans which might be useful in some cases, but not in others. Regarding the *confirmPassword* field you can always mark it as *@Transient* in your entity so that the value does not get persisted.

Personally I would probably disable the Spring validation via @Valid, because it is not standard. Bean Validation on JPA life cycle events on the other hand are. I guess this is another matter of taste. Having both seems unnecessary though.

Comment: Its already marked transient, but validator still throws constraint violation as its marked NotEmpty also.  So best approach so far seems to have two separate beans (form and entity) and write code for coversion between them which is not so good.  Still waiting for a better approach though.

Comment: At the time of persisting (when the event triggers) the field should be set and validated. I guess your problem occurs when you load the entity and then change and persist it again. One solution is to set the _confirmPassword_ field when the entity is loaded. Via a _@PostLoad_ for example.

Comment: yes, using `@PostLoad` for setting such view only fields is good workaround.